# When can we find coset representatives that generate the original group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ denote a group and consider a subgroup $H \subseteq G$. Then the left cosets of $H$ form a partitioning of $G$ (irrespective of whether or not $H$ is normal). Call this partitioning $\Pi_H$. By a choice function on $\Pi_H$, let us mean a function $f : \Pi_H \rightarrow G$ such that $f(\pi) \in \pi$ for all $\pi \in \Pi_H$.

(Assume the axiom of choice, so that every partitioning has a choice function.)

Now for some combinations of a group $G$ and a subgroup $H \subseteq G$, there is a choice function on the corresponding $\Pi_H$ with the property that its image generates $G.$ For a trivial example, take $H = \{1\},$ in other words suppose $H$ is the minimum subgroup of $G$. Then $\Pi_H$ is the finest partitioning of $G$, so there is only one choice function on $\Pi_H,$ and the image of that choice function is all of $G$.

For other combinations of $G$ and $H$, there is no such choice function. For example, suppose $G$ is non-cyclic and take $H=G$. Then every choice function on $\Pi_H$ has singleton image, which therefore cannot generate $G$.

> **Q.** For which groups $G$ and subgroups $H \subseteq G$ does there exist a choice function on the set of all cosets of $H$
>   with the property that the image of that choice function generates the
>   entirety of $G$?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there were any answer more useful than a disguised version of "there is one when there is, and there isn't one when there isn't".